# Warning: tensorflow: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have an issue with tf.callbacks.ModelChekpoint.
As you can see in my log file, the warning comes always before the last iteration where the val_accuracy is calculated. Therefore, Modelcheckpoint never finds the val_accuracy

[image]

The validation losses are not even avail in log files

these are the metrics of log
`loss: 2.4456 - table_mask_loss: 0.3486 - col_mask_loss: 0.3167 - table_mask_accuracy: 0.8739 - col_mask_accuracy: 0.8705`

This is my code

```
filepath = "/content/table_net.h5"
model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("table_net.h5", monitor = 'val_accuracy', save_best_only=True, verbose = 0, mode="min",save_freq='epoch')



es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='min', patience=5,)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=init_lr, epsilon=1e-8,),
              loss=losses,
              metrics=['accuracy'] )

EPOCHS = 5
VAL_SUBSPLITS = 30
VALIDATION_STEPS = len(X_test)//BATCH_SIZE//VAL_SUBSPLITS


history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                              epochs=EPOCHS,
                              steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
                              validation_data=test_dataset,
                              validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
                              callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

Comment: Your model has multiple outputs, not one, so there is no metric called val_acc, as it would make no sense. Use a metric name that actually exists in your model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I'm training the table detection model and i get the table-wise losses as well as column wise losses. I'm expecting the val_accuracy

Comment: That does not change what I said, your model has two outputs, right? Which would be val_accuracy?